# What are the steps to do a single sign-on in iTop with the web server on Windows?

Tags: php, single-sign-on

I want to make a single sign-on in iTop. The environment of web server is running on Windows, and I want the authentication to be transparent to the end users

I read [this itophub wiki page on user authentication options](https://www.itophub.io/wiki/page?id=latest%3Aadmin%3Auser_authentication_options) first. I understand that the authentication type must be external (please tell me if my understanding is wrong)

And I read this note:

> Single Sign-On on Windows
>
> Since iTop uses the PHP variable `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` to identify external users, this becomes really simple if your web server is running on Windows. Using IIS you can rely on the Integrated Windows Authentication and if using Apache you can use the `sspi_auth_module`. Both will set the variable `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` to the authenticated user as `“DOMAIN\USERNAME”`. Simply create your External users names the same way: `DOMAIN\USERNAME` and the iTop authentication will be transparent to your end users

I understand this note but I don't know what I should do exactly. I mean, how can I implement it?

I do not have enough information about this subject. Any help is appreciated.